# How can Mechanize keep a session until I end the script manually?

Tags: ruby, session, mechanize

There is a webpage I need open during my whole work day. I wrote a script in Ruby using Mechanize which works fine, however, the page is closed when the script ends.

I found a method using an endless-loop and `sleep(x)`, but I still think that's not a good method. I'm afraid it would take too much memory.

Is there any way to keep the session open until I end the script manually?

Here is my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

def autoOpen (loginname, loginpasswd)
    p = Mechanize.new
    p.agent.http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    page = p.get('https://www.webpage.com/index.cgi')
    logpage = page.form_with(:method => "POST")
    logpage.username = loginname
    logpage.password = loginpasswd
    succpage = logpage.submit(logpage.button_with(:name => 'Submit'))
end

while 1 == 1
    if false == system('ping www.webpage.com > tmp')
        autoOpen('username', 'password')
    end
    sleep(1)
end
```

Actually, it will not work, even if I add the endless-loop.

As @theTinMan said, Mechanize just opens the page and get the contents/object, it cannot **stay** in the page.

Is there a solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "webpage needs to be opening"? Mechanize reads a page once, and doesn't keep it open. It temporarily caches what it read, so you can find elements in the page, but it's not a browser, nor does it act like one.

Comment: This doesn't take much memory at all: `loop.do{sleep x}`. Maybe you should show some code.

Comment: Hi @theTinMan that means, there is a proxy (proxy is a webpage), I needs to open it in browser every whole day. Thanks for your explain, is there any method can **hold** the session?

Comment: Hi @pguardiario , I have show the code, but **loop** cannot work, because Mechanize cannot **stay** in that page.

Comment: You're session won't 'stay alive' if you create a new Mechanize object every time. I wish I could help more but you also seem to be missing a basic understanding of how ruby works.

Comment: Hi @pguardiario , could you give me more clue?

Comment: You really need something that will open your browser to a specific page daily. 

You don't say what OS you are on, but all of them have the ability to be scripted. A script can open a browser page. 

Just figure out how to run the script at a certain time. On Mac OS and Linux that is easy, just run something from cron.

I think your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, and on-topic for http://superuser.com.

Comment: Hi @theTinMan, the reason of I haven't figure out the OS is, I need open that page in both Windows and Linux. As your answered, Watir is a human-like tools, so I think it will not using schedule tools any more. I will have a try. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you could try is to use [Watir](http://watir.com/) to open a browser window.

Watir isn't like Mechanize; Mechanize is a page parser that lets you fill in forms and submit them, and, as a side feature, look through the DOM of a page to find things.

Instead, Watir tells the browser how to act like a user, so opening a page, clicking on a button, getting the contents of a field or entering text into a field is all doable. That might spoof your proxy system into thinking you're actually using the page.

But, really, I think you're trying to hack a system that is probably going to surprise you. If *I* wrote a proxy, I'd be watching to see if there was traffic being passed by a session. If there wasn't I'd close it. Proxy servers are network servers, and have limited resources too, so if there are a lot of people with sessions open and not using it those resources are being wasted. So don't be surprised if simply opening a browser page isn't the real fix.

Instead, maybe you need to learn more about that particular proxy and see if you can open a tunnel through it, and keep that open via a ping or periodic request to a remote host.

Again, you don't tell  us nearly enough to give you any sort of usable answer. It sounds like you don't know enough about the proxy you're trying to fool, so there is going to be a lot of experimenting in your future.

As a Ruby-coding tip, I'd write your code more like:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

def auto_open(name, password)
  p = Mechanize.new
  p.agent.http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  logpage = p.get('https://www.webpage.com/index.cgi').form_with(:method => "POST")
  logpage.username = name
  logpage.password = password
  logpage.submit(logpage.button_with(:name => 'Submit'))
end

while true
  if system('ping -c1 www.webpage.com > /dev/null')
    sleep(1)
  else
    auto_open('username', 'password')
  end
end
```

That code still won't work, but it's more Ruby-like.

Also, you might want to look at using `ping -i 60 www.webpage.com > /dev/null`. `-i n` means "wait `n` seconds between pings".

Comment: How nice of you, @theTinMan, I'm a totally fresh. Thanks for you so patient exposition.